# Test is not executing on AppCenter - Getting Failed every-time. - Executing fine in Local

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

Our Team got stuck in issue about appcenter (test could) execution of Test Script, and looking for any solutions.

First of all **Note that**, Our tests are executing nicely in local machine with Emulator as well as real devices without any issue.

Now problem is, **if I try to run** our test in App Center (in Cloud), at that time it gets failed on Startup. Below is the Snap of Command line output and more details about my execution in App Center Cloud.

After a build, we use below command line to upload and run tests in App center.

"appcenter test run uitest --app "ssidi/ZC-Mobile-Test-Xamarin" --devices "ssidi/samsung-s7-edge" --app-path C:\SAJIDSIDI\Xamarin\Projects\CurrentWorkingProject\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\APK\ZCXamarinQA_2.52.apk --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir C:\SAJIDSIDI\Xamarin\Projects\CurrentWorkingProject\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\bin\Debug --include C:\SAJIDSIDI\Xamarin\Projects\CurrentWorkingProject\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\bin\Debug\TestData.xlsx"

**Command line Execution in NuGet Package Manager Console.**

[image: Command line Execution in NuGet Package Manager Console]

**Device LOG URL**
https://testcloud-artifacts.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/0b76f8bc-c833-4b88-ae9c-a27c0127b00e/f6967bb5-59d4-4ad9-a7f4-9134f4fbc2c2?response-cache-control=max-age%3D315576000&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI4UZT4FCOF2OTJYQ&Signature=d9TslNaim%2Bwj/kSFNIsekS6rVAY%3D&Expires=1735689600

**Test LOG URL**
https://testcloud-artifacts.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/0b76f8bc-c833-4b88-ae9c-a27c0127b00e/8bf8747a-f550-4ddd-917a-204d934a1c87?response-cache-control=max-age%3D315576000&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI4UZT4FCOF2OTJYQ&Signature=wjv2DzgU0ttaPHQkIrnYFGfFo4Q%3D&Expires=1735689600

Note that We have a DataFile (.xlsx) from where we are using test data, and also some SQL Queries from our DataBase Servers to execution data.

**Additional Details.**

OS and Device:
-   We using Samsung Galaxy S6 and S7 with Android 6.0.1 and 7.0 Version to run test in Local and same is selected in appcenter (see command line)

**Project Configuration**

- Our Project has below packages are installed

o    Xamarin.UI.test (2.2.4)

o    NUnit (2.6.4)

o   Microsoft.AppCenter.1.5.0

o   Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics.1.5.0

o   Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.1.5.0

o   Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.1.5.0

Comment: What is the specific error causing the failure?

Answer (score 0):

> Errors and Failures:
>   1) SetUp Error : ZeroChaosUITest.Tests(Android).FilterAndApproveStaffAugReq
>      SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).
>   Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later.

You are trying to use an `.xlsx` (`OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open`) in your test(s) and the MDAC components are not installed on the test server.

Note: This error is directly listed in your test log

Comment: yes, I noticed this Error but as i am trying to Run in App Center Cloud, how to resolved this one?   Or what alternate i can use?

Comment: I think the simplest way would be to use a csv (or a json file if your data needs to be more complex).